# Is there a more Pythonic/elegant way to expand the dimensions of a Numpy Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

What I am trying to do right now is:

```
x = x[:, None,  None,  None,  None,  None,  None,  None,  None,  None]
```

Basically, I want to expand my Numpy array by 9 dimensions. Or some N number of dimensions where N might not be known in advance!

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative approach could be with `reshaping` -

```
x.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*N)  # N is no. of dims to be appended
```

So, basically for the `None's` that correspond to singleton dimensions, we are using a shape of length `1` along those dims. For the first axis, we are using a shape of `-1` to *push all elements* into it.

Sample run -

```
In [119]: x = np.array([2,5,6,4])

In [120]: x.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*9).shape
Out[120]: (4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Further to this, if you want to have x's shape show up in the middle of the resulting array's shape, you can do something like `x.reshape((1,) + x.shape + (1,)*(N-1))`
I needed this when adding a channel to my image as the last dimension, and making it into a batch of images by adding a first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

To abbreviate the expression (and make it work for arbitrary dimensions chosen at runtime), you could just generate the index on the fly:

```
x = x[(slice(None),)+(None,)*9]
```

If you want to put your slice to a different position, the index tuple can be adjusted accordingly.

Note, there will be no benefit regarding performance. This is just more concise writing and may be even less readable than writing out the `None`s

Furthermore, the reshape solution has similar performance.