# Subtract over last axis of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

> I want to subtract all values in a[nn,...,0] by b[nn] while
>   keeping the original structure of the array *a*.

---

I have a problem with indexing and elementwise subtraction from an ndnumpy array.
In my case, array *a* has 6 dimensions

```
In[]: a.shape
Out[]: (101, 256, 1, 3, 1, 10)
```

For the sake of consistency, the lowest dimension *N=0* has 10 elements and the highest *N=5* has 101 elements.

I also have a 1D array *b* which is the same size as the highest
dimension in *a*.

```
In[]: b.shape
Out[]: (101,)
```

I want to subtract *b* from *a* in such a way that the *nn*-th element in *b* is
subtracted from the values *a[nn,...,0]*. I know I can do this using for loops, but it should also be possible to broadcast *b* in such a way that I can use something like

```
In[]: c= a[:,...,0]-b[somehow broadcastet or reshaped]
In[]: c.shape()
Out[]:  (101, 256, 1, 3, 1, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed do this taking advantage of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Lets start by generating some random `ndarrays` of the specified shape in order to check that the final dimensions are as expected:

```
a = np.random.rand(101, 256, 1, 3, 1, 10)
b = np.random.rand(101)
```

In this case you would have to add up to `a.ndim` dimensions to `b` so that each value in `b` is subtracted to each of the values in the last dimension of `a`. Following the idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069249/9698684) post we can add up to `a.ndim` new dimensionsions in a more concise way using [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) as follows:

```
b = b.reshape((-1,) + (1,)*(a.ndim-1))
print(b.shape)
# (101, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Now we could subtract `b` from `a` as required by doing:

```
a[..., 0, None] = a[..., 0, None] - b.reshape((-1,) + (1,) * (a.ndim-1))
```

And if we check the shape of `a`:

```
print(a.shape)
# (101, 256, 1, 3, 1, 10)
```

---

#### Details

Here are some explanations on some questions that might arise from the previous answer. Lets consider the following simpler example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(a)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
print(a.shape)
# (2, 3)

b = np.array([1,1])[:,None]
array([[1],
       [1]])
print(b.shape)
# (2, 1)
```

So for this example, we could apply the same logic as the solution above with:

```
a[:,0,None] = a[:,0,None] - b

array([[0, 2, 3],
       [3, 5, 6]])
```

Which by inspecting the resulting array, as expected `b` has been subtracted from `a` on the first index along its last axis, so the first column in all rows.

---

So first point,

> Why do we have to add a new axis in `a` for subtraction?

It is necessary to add a new axis to `a` given the shape of `b`. Note that `b` is a 2-dimensional array `array([[1],[1]])`, so if you were to subtract it directly from `a`, you would get:

```
a[..., 0] - b
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 3]])
```

So, what has happened here is that the smaller array, i.e. the first term, which is simply a `1D` view slice from `a`, `array([1, 4])`, has been broadcasted across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes.

This would not be necessary if the shape of `b` were instead `(2,)`:

```
b = np.array([1,1])
a[:,0] - b
# array([0, 3])
```

But due to the way in which `b` in the actual solution has been defined, it has the same amount of dimensions as `a`. So in order to obtain the correct output, we must add a new axis to `a`:

```
a[:,0,None] - b
array([[0],
       [3]])
```

This way we obtain the correct output.

---

> With the method above it doesn't seem possible to assign the difference to a new array acting as a "corrected copy" of a?

The answer to this question can be understood by taking a look at the result from the subtraction:

```
c = a[:,0,None] - b
c.shape
(2, 1)
```

So here `a[:,0,None]` is what is called a "sliced view" of `a`. So note that by assigning this result to `c`, you are only saving the actual `sliced wiew` of `a`, not the entire `ndarray`. If you want to modify `a` on the same positions of the actual slice, you will have to assign it to a same sliced view of `a`, so:

```
a[:,0,None] = a[:,0,None] - b
print(a.shape)
# (2, 3)
```

Now the result does have the expected output, as we have only modified a slice of `a`. If you did want to save a copy of the original `ndarray` you could use [`np.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html), which will return an actual copy rather than a slice of `a`, and then assign the result to the "corrected copy":

```
a_c = np.copy(a)
a_c[:,0,None] = a[:,0,None] - b
```

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you very much for your time.